# What options can be passed through instagrams tag_recent_media method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram, optional-parameters, instagram-api

I'm trying to use the instagram gem with rails 4.1.8 to pull images with the tag "cat" from a specific date range. In my controller I have

```
        @instagram_cats = Instagram.tag_recent_media('cat', {count: 10 })
```

In the tutorial I found for configuration, count was already given as an option. I've been trying to find what other options I can pass, but I can't find a reasonable list or tutorial that says I can specify a date range. What other options can be passed with the api?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post an answer since the other commenter deleted his answer.

The available options are `count` `min_id` and `max_id`

According to their doc for the gem on git hub, `min_id` should return results with a min_tag_id greater than (newer) than the min_tag_id and the opposite for `max_id`

Found via Github
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/client/tags.rb